# How to back to mainactivity when I click on backbutton?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

```
Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  }else {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

I have a nav drawer with some items and fragments. When I click on an Item, obviously open a fragment, but how to when any fragment is open backbutton backs to mainactivity layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the back button inside the fragment and handling using a fragment class. You can use this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // do something
    return true;  // return true if back handled, false otherwise
}

return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in your MainActivity itself:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
     } else if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     } else {
         super.onBackPressed(); 
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to manually maintain all fragment in mainActivity Backpressed(), you can find which fragment is open now using this senior you can replace main fragment on backButton.